# Are Neo4j user defined procedures the best way to implement doubly linked lists in my graph database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am implementing an application that uses the Neo4j graph database.

I have a requirement to implement doubly linked lists in my graph.  Doing this in Cypher can be done using large and complex queries.  I am thinking that a better way to do this would be to implement the doubly linked list feature via user defined procedures.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, a caution:**

In Neo4j, a doubly-linked list won't buy you much. You can already traverse a relationship in the opposite direction, so if this is purely for traversal, it's not needed at all, and you shouldn't see performance improvement from it unless special cases are in play in your data model.

If you do need to know how to create a doubly-linked list, then see below:

You'll probably want APOC Procedures for this, [apoc.nodes.link() in the Creating Data section](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) is a procedure that takes in a collection of nodes and allows you to create relationships between each of the nodes in a linked-list style.

Unfortunately APOC doesn't have a function to reverse the list so you can run apoc.nodes.link() again, so you'll have to follow-up either with a query for the same nodes but in reverse order, or a query to match on any two nodes that are linked and merge in the second relationship.

An example on the Movies graph:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WITH m
ORDER BY m.released ASC
WITH COLLECT(m) as movies
CALL apoc.nodes.link(movies, 'Next')
MATCH (m:Movie)-[:Next]->(n:Movie)
MERGE (n)-[:Prev]->(m)
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you for the pointer to apoc, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Question: I did not see any methods for adding, removing or inserting elements into a doubly linked list, are those available in apoc?

Comment: The linked list here is not a well-defined 'thing' in Neo4j, it's just an arrangement of nodes and relationships which just happens to be a linked list structure. You would need to create and reuse queries which manually handle node deletion and insertion and rearrange the relationships accordingly, and you'll likely need to lock on the nodes involved (you can do this by removing a non-existent property on the nodes to engage a write-lock) if there's a chance concurrent alterations can occur. Because of this complexity, it actually may be a good idea to consider user defined procedures.

Comment: If I implement list manipulation operations within a single transaction, would I need to really do any locking?

Comment: I think you still would, though I'm still a novice on Neo4j concurrency troubleshooting/optimization. APOC has some [locking functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_locking) that might make the locking itself a bit easier, once you identify the nodes to lock.

Comment: It may be worth asking about how to handle concurrent operations on the structure as a new question, I'd like to get a bit of clarification on this myself.

Comment: Learning as I go here… the transaction object exposes a method for acquiring write-locks, and I think that if I acquire a write lock on the list head while manipulating the entries on the list, then that will give me the consistency I am looking for, does that seem reasonable?

Comment: If all manipulations first lock on the head, and if the head itself doesn't change, then that seems reasonable, but it may still be worth asking.

Comment: Just a quick update, a `reverse()` function is available both with pure Cypher and in APOC (`apoc.coll.reverse()`), so that will make it easier to create the relationships in the opposite direction (if actually needed). Also, it's a good idea to have a list or zeroth node that always exists for a list (that could point to the head and/or tail of the list and maybe maintain list metadata), as that provides an invariant node that you can always lock onto before any list manipulations to prevent race conditions that could corrupt the list.